# How to make external hard drive with Ubuntu bootable

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb

I've installed Ubuntu on my Toshiba 500GB external HDD from liveCD. There's there, because I can see from my software on Win7 that there is 10GB used on the disk, so it is Ubuntu I guess. Now I'm facing the problem, how can I make the external HDD bootable? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your installation completed successfully, the drive should already be marked bootable. Enter your bios on boot(F2 or F12) to change your boot sequence and place your external disk(USB I guess) before hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed GRUB, *on the external drive* (Made that mistake once... or twice...).

To boot a removable HDD you need to catch not the bios config but the boot device menu (On one of my comps it's `ESC`, on one it's `F8`, on one `F12`) during POST, because as soon as you disconnect the device the bios will "forget" it.

Also, on my laptop I have to boot **Windows** on *power-up* and then *reboot* into **Ubuntu** because the *USB* ports aren't powered up early enough or something.

Hope that helps.